# lower bounds for exact algorithms

Tags: algorithms, np-hard

I am working on building exact algorithms for NP-hard problems. Let's consider an NP-hard problem $P$. The brute force approach runs in $2^n$ time. In order to prove that there is no $2^{o(n)}$ time algorithm for $P$, we provide a reduction from the 3-SAT problem (Assuming ETH holds).
  I want to prove that no exact algorithm exists that runs in time $c^n$ for any value of $c$ less than two. In other words, I would like to prove that there is no better algorithm than brute force. How is this done?

Answer (score -1):

That is very unlikely to be true, because the problem size n will depend on exactly how problem instances are represented.

If one representation is 20% larger, then the time to solve the problem is unaffected, but the time would be not $2^n$ but $2^{n/1.2}$ or $c^n$ for $c = 2^{1/1.2}$.

And many problems have solutions that are exponential but much faster than $2^n$.